# Refresh a ListBox in ASP.NET MVC 2 with jQuery

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, jquery

I've looked around on SO to see if this has been asked before and couldn't find anything (so if it has indeed been asked before then I apologize.

Here's what I'm trying to do, a user can select from a list of skills for their profile, if a skill they want isn't in the list then they can add it to the database, I have that accomplished with WCF & jQuery AJAX. Here's the code for that:

```
$("#AddNewSkill").click(function () {
    $("#AddNewSkill").attr("disabled", true);
    $("#newSkill").attr("disabled", true);
    var newSkill = $("#newSkill").val();
    var data = { name: $("#newSkill").val(), description: "", type: "Skill" };
    data = JSON.stringify(data)
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "../WeddingPhotographerService.svc/AddNew",
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function () {
            successCall('#newSkill', '#AddNewSkill');
            //$('#SkillListViewContainer').load('../Account/GetSkillControl');
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            $("#AddSkillError").text(msg.d);
            $("#AddSkill").attr("disabled", false);
            $("#NewSkill").attr("disabled", false);
        }
    });
});
```

Here's the method in the AJAX-Enabled WCF service:

```
[OperationContract]
public bool AddNew(string name, string description, string type)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case "":
            goto default;
        case "skill":
            IRepository<Skill> skillRepo = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IRepository<Skill>>();
            var skill = new Skill { Name = name, Description = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(description)) ? string.Empty : description };
            skillRepo.Save(skill);
            return true;
        case "equipment":
            IRepository<Equipment> eqRep = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IRepository<Equipment>>();
            var eq = new Equipment { Name = name, Description = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(description)) ? string.Empty : description };
            eqRep.Save(eq);
            return true;
        case "occasion":
            IRepository<Occassion> occRepo = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IRepository<Occassion>>();
            var oc = new Occassion { Name = name, Description = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(description)) ? string.Empty : description };
            occRepo.Save(oc);
            return true;
        default:
            IRepository<Skill> repo = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IRepository<Skill>>();
            var s = new Skill { Name = name, Description = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(description)) ? string.Empty : description };
            repo.Save(s);
            return true;
    }
}
```

It's kind of ugly but I'll optimize it once I have this 2nd part working. Here's how the ListBox is being loaded in the view:

```
<%: Html.ListBox("Skills", Model.SkillList, new { @style = "width:157px; height:90px;background:#e2f0f1;", @size = "3", @class = "inputbox" })%>
```

Which comes from *RegistrationModelView.cs*, here's *SkillList* in my model view:

```
private MultiSelectList GetSkills(string[] selectedValues)
{
    List<Skill> list = new List<Skill>();
    IRepository<Skill> skills = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IRepository<Skill>>();

    foreach (Skill skill in skills.GetAll())
    {
        list.Add(new Skill()
        {
            Key = skill.Key,
            Name = skill.Name,
            Description = ""
        });                
    }
    return new MultiSelectList(list, "Key", "Name", selectedValues);
}
```

And the action in *AccountController.cs* that loads the view

```
[MoveFormsScript]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(new RegistrationModelView());
}
```

I'm pretty sure all the code I posted (other than how the new item is added with the WCF service and the jQuery for consuming said service is irrelevant but I thought I'd offer as much information as possible).

Like I said the new value is added to the database no problem, my issue is updating the ListBox to reflect the new values. Anyone got any ideas and can help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I mucked around until I found something that does what I need it to do. It may not be the most efficient or elegant way to accomplish the task but it at least works (Maybe someone will come along with a different solution some day).

What I ended up doing was make another *$,ajax()* call in the *success* of the first call like this

```
$("#AddNewSkill").click(function () {
    $("#AddNewSkill").attr("disabled", true);
    $("#newSkill").attr("disabled", true);
    var data = { name: $("#newSkill").val(), description: "", type: "skill" };
    data = JSON.stringify(data)
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "../WeddingPhotographerService.svc/AddNew",
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function () {
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                datatype:"json",
                url: "../Account/GetSkills",
                success:updateSkillsListBox
            });
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            alert(msg.d);
        }
    });
});

function updateSkillsListBox(data, status) {
    $("#Skills").html("");
    for(var d in data) {
        $("<option value=\"" + data[d].Value + "\">" + data[d].Name + "</option>").appendTo("#Skills");
}
```